# Handbook of basic algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Similarly to how an analyst may be looking for an analysis handbook listing the general solutions to different integrals (as for example in Schaum's [Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables](http://www2.ee.ufpe.br/codec/colecao%20schaum%27s%20%28mathematical%20%20-%20formulas%20and%20tables%29.pdf) does) I am looking for a handbook on basic (Groups, Rings, Vector Spaces, Modules,...- nothing fancy) algebra that systematically (!) states facts about how certain properties behave w.r.t. basic constructions.

The answers to some of those types of questions are well known, because they are so important (eg. Hilbert Basis Theorem: $R$ noetherian $\Rightarrow$ $R[X]$ noetherian). Some are easy to remember (e.g. the product of an integral domain is not in general an integral domain). Others, however, are neither, but still arise from time to time, when trying to prove something (e.g. in a UFD, is a ring prime if and only if every element of its minimal generating set if prime?). In other words: A list of lemmas (not even necessarily with proofs) stating natural (!) assertions.

For example, in such a book one may find a table for rings where the column-heads are classifying conditions of rings (such as Integral Domain, Principal Ideal Domain, Reduced, ...) and in the row-heads basic constructions (such as Product, Subring, Intersection, ...) and every cell says "true" if the [*construction*] of a ring with [*property*] has [*property*]" and "false" if not.

Something similar to maybe [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage) for Category Theory or [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) for Group Theory. Note though, that neither is a precise analogy to what I'm looking for. Everything I have found yet is either much close to a textbook states too few theorem or in a (seemingly) non-systematic manner.

Let me repeat, I am not looking for a textbook, but a handbook; somewhat similar to how an engineer may use a handbook on mechanics.

Now, my question: Does anybody know of a book or website of that type? Or have any other comments?

Comment: I'm trying to do [something like this for rings at the Database of ring theory](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/theorems/) but currently that section is only in its beginnings.  Suggestions for additions are appreciated.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes!! That's great. Indeed, rings and commutative algebra were my primary motivation for this question.

Comment: Well, I look forward to hearing your input and feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

One example is the book series

[Handbook of Algebra](https://www.elsevier.com/books/book-series/handbook-of-algebra),

edited by  M. Hazewinkel.

Comment: True, but this is unfortunately an example for those books that are more like a textbook, and less like a database.